# jQuery val function not working on a hidden field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my `HTML`code:

```
<div style='display:none;' id='allformid'>
    <div>
        <form action='#'>
              <input type='text' name='name' id='named'/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is my `jQuery` code to set the value of the input text box:

```
$("#allformid  #named").val('abcd');
```

This `jQuery` code is correct, but the form value is not changed.

Comment: because the div is hidden!!! remove `style='display:none;'`

Comment: If you wanted a hidden field, use `<input type='hidden'>` rather than hiding the input inside a div.

Comment: also since you have an id for the input element `$('#named').val('abcd');`

Comment: It probably is changed - it just doesn't look like it has.  Open the console and enter `$("#named").val();`  It will show you the actual value

Comment: no div hidden is required.

Comment: then did you add the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: It does work.  Check this jsfiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/SU7tp/

Comment: (smells like XY problem) the code you provided works fine... you migth want to explain a little better what's wrong on your page. I see a `display:block;` why? is this from a plugin you need to change?

Comment: @Archer yes dear console.log() is print value. but value is not set in text field.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it looks like in the DOM.  The value *is* there or `.val()` would not return it.  Please explain why you say it's not there.

Comment: Actually, use my example jsfiddle and then use the DOM inspector to remove `display:none` from the div and you will see the value in the text box.

Comment: Are you *showing* `#allformid` at any point? If not, any particular reason you're not just using `<input type="hidden">` if you want a hidden input?

Comment: @renishkhunt can you add a `console.log('length', $("#allformid  #named").length)` just before the value is set and see what is happening

Comment: my previous question is not yet answered.... is the code in a dom ready handler??? like `jQuery(function(){...})`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried the same code it works fine. How did you test that the code works or not?

If you check the inspect element, it will not show value="abcd".
But if you make the div visible, you can see the value is given. But the value gets set. 
You can also test the value by getting the value in the js console like this:

`$("#allformid  #named").val();`

However if you want it to display as value="abcd", you will need to write `$("#allformid  #named").attr("value",'abcd');`

Comment: $("#named").attr("value",'abcd'); this is not working dear please help.

Comment: I have tried it already. The issue seems to be somewhere else. Does it show any errors?
how are you checking if it works or not?

Comment: i would not recommend removing #allformid 
because incase you happen to set the id for any other element to named, it will select this element too.

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<form action='#'>
      <input type='hidden' value='' name='name' id='named'/>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#named").val('abcd');
```

Comment: This is no different from the question, other than missing out the unrequired and irrelevant form ID from the selector.

Comment: yeah true this is just a filtered form of the question itself

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#' + $('#Hiddenfield1').val()).val('Hello');
```

**Source:**
http://forums.asp.net/t/2003756.aspx?How+to+use+Jquery+to+set+a+textbox+of+a+dynamic+control